# Progress OpenEdge - TempTable to file - an easy way?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I would like an really easy way to see the content in any temptable in Progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out an easy way to dump a temp-table to file using Json (from 10.2B).
WRITE-JSON is the trick!!

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttTmp                                             
  FIELD FieldA          AS CHAR                                         
  FIELD FieldB          AS CHAR.                                        

CREATE ttTmp.                                                           
ASSIGN ttTmp.FieldA = "A"                                               
      ttTmp.FieldB = "B".                                               

DEFINE VARIABLE tthTmp AS HANDLE  NO-UNDO. /* Handle to temptable */    
DEFINE VARIABLE lReturnValue AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.                        
tthTmp = TEMP-TABLE ttTmp:HANDLE.                                       


lReturnValue = tthTmp:WRITE-JSON("FILE", "c:\temp\tthTmp.txt", TRUE, ?).

/* Output File tthTmp.txt                                               
{"ttTmp": [                                                             
  {                                                                     
    "FieldA": "A",                                                      
    "FieldB": "B"                                                       
  }                                                                     
]}                                                                      
 Output File tthTmp.txt */
```

Comment: Yes, if JSON is what you're after that's a great way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You could also for instance produce XML

```
tthTmp:WRITE-XML("FILE","c:\temp\tt.xml", TRUE).
```

or (maybe not quite as easy) output as a semi colon delimited file

```
OUTPUT TO c:\temp\file.txt.
FOR EACH ttTmp:
  EXPORT DELIMITER ";" ttTmp.
END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Comment: write-json is also available